# Type mismatch on my stored procedure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, vb6, sql-server-2012

I have a button that calls a stored procedure in my database on click. The code in my VB6 form is as follows

```
 Dim dbDlrID As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim cmdDlrID As New ADODB.Command
 Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
 Dim i As Integer

 Set dbDlrID = New ADODB.Connection
  With dbDlrID
    .ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};database=dbname;    server=servname;uid=;pwd=;"
```

.Open
     End With

```
 Set cmdDlrID = New ADODB.Command
 cmdDlrID.CommandText = "InsertLookupLog"
 cmdDlrID.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
 cmdDlrID.CommandTimeout = 15
Set cmdDlrID.ActiveConnection = dbDlrID

  Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@ContractNumberField", adVarChar, adParamInput,  "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@ContractSuffix", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@CustomerLastName", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@CustomerFirstName", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@Last6OfVin", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@DealershipName", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@ClaimNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
  Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@PortalClaimNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@RONumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@ContractID", adChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@LookUpUser", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@LookUpTime", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@Department", adVarChar, adParamInput, "HI")
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm

 cmdDlrID.Execute
```

Iv stepped through it and on the very first parmeter i get a "run-time error '13' Type mismatch"

The type for ContractNumberField is varchar(50). What am i missing here?

Comment: You're creating the `LookUpTime` parameter twice - that doesn't sound like a good thing. Nor does it sound good that all these "number" fields are varchar...

Comment: fixed, im just trying to get it to work for now before i go into detail with datatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out, adding "50" as an argument between HI and adParamInput

Comment: Yes, make sure you know the syntax for the ADO methods. The [API reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209(v=vs.85).aspx) will be helpful with that.